# Comma Delimited List REGEX in MySQL with Integer

Tags: mysql, regex

I can use the regex comparing a comma delimited list of GUID against a column that is a string, but I am having trouble doing it with an integer like the one below.  Am I doing something wrong or is this not possible?

```
select * from sims_role where organization_id REGEXP '4929,4930'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want:

```
select * from sims_role where organization_id REGEXP '^(4929|4930)$'
```

What you've used is identical to:

```
select * from sims_role where organization_id LIKE '%4929,4930%'
```

Comment: Yep it was the pipe I was missing doh!